# Arduino - MagStripe card.available pauses and no other code can run

Tags: c++, arduino

I am using the MagStrip library (https://github.com/carlosefr/magstripelib). In my main loop I call the function which runs the code:

```
void magcardFunc()
{
static const byte DATA_BUFFER_LEN = 108;
static char magcard[DATA_BUFFER_LEN];
  
// Don't do anything if there isn't a card present

  if (!card.available()) {
    return;
  }

    // Read the card into the buffer "magcard" (as a null-terminated string)
  short chars = card.read(magcard, DATA_BUFFER_LEN);

  if (chars < 0) {
    Serial.print("bad read");
    return;
  }
  
  // Send the data to the computer if data was read
  if (chars != 0) {
    Serial.print(magcardstr);
  }
}
```

The code successfully reads a magnetic card when inserted.

The problem is, I have other functions which are called from the main loop but they do not get called as the code pauses at:

```
if (!card.available()) {
    return;
  }

    // Read the card into the buffer "magcard" (as a null-terminated string)
  short chars = card.read(magcard, DATA_BUFFER_LEN);
```

If I insert a card into my mag reader (and leave it there), the program continues and the other functions are called. I want the main loop to continue and the other functions be called without having to leave a card inserted.

I have tried removing the IF statement:

```
if (!card.available()) {
    return;
  }
```

and I have tried reversing it

```
if (card.available()) {
    return;
  }
```

If I reverse it as above, the other functions run but when I do swipe a card, it is not read.
I get no compiler errors.

EDIT:
Here is an example sketch which replicates the problem. I noticed that this sketch actually did call the otherFunc when the mag card reader was unplugged. I am not sure why when it is plugged in it pauses. Maybe an interrupt is always on?

```
#include <MagStripe.h>

void magcardFunc();
void otherFunc();

MagStripe card;

static const byte DATA_BUFFER_LEN = 108;
static char data[DATA_BUFFER_LEN];


void setup()
{
  // The card data will be sent over serial...
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Initialize the library for reading track 2...
  card.begin(2);
}


void loop()
{
  magcardFunc();
  otherFunc();
}
 
void magcardFunc()
{
  // Don't do anything if there isn't a card present...
  if (!card.available()) {
    return;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had a look at the library implementation and it seems your original "if !available" statement is fine. (It is also the first thing done in the read( ) function.)  The read function then goes into a read loop that only exits when the card is "no longer available" otherwise infinite.  So in short, I can't see why it shouldn't work other that some sort of hardware problem. The available( ) function only reads "pin_cls" which one provides in the card.begin(2) call.

Comment: Thanks @mmixLinus - I understand the read/available functions but I do not know why my magcardFunc() function does not return when a card is not inserted.   if (!card.available()) {
    return;
}